# How do I update DataTables columns (and other properties) dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There are a few questions here on SO about updating the columns in DataTables dynamically, but they all seem very out of date as they reference deprecated properties like `aoColumns`.

My code looks something like this:

```
var oTableOptions = {
    columns: [
        {title: "Column 1", data: "col1"},
        {title: "Column 2", data: "col2"},
        {title: "Column 3", data: "col3"}
    ],
    order: [
        [0, 'desc'],
        [1, 'asc']
    ],
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false
}

var dt = $('#tableId').DataTable(oTableOptions);
```

Couple of questions:

1. **How do I update the default sorting order?** If I want to dynamically change it to something like  `[[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc']]` instead (the next time the table is redrawn), how do I do this?

The following code *doesn't* work, so what am I missing?

```
dt.order = [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc']];
dt.ajax.reload();
```

2. **How do I rename an existing column?** I couldn't find any documented method for doing this. Is there one, or do I just have to use jQuery directly?
3. **How do I add/remove columns?**

Answer (score 4):

```js
var oTableOptions = {
    columns: [
        {title: "Column 1", data: "col1"},
        {title: "Column 2", data: "col2"},
        {title: "Column 3", data: "col3"},
        {title: "Column 4", data: "col4"}
    ],
    order: [
        [0, 'desc'],
        [1, 'asc']
    ],
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false
}

var dt = $('#tableId').DataTable(oTableOptions);

// Later...

var nTableOptions = {
    columns: [
        {title: "Column 1", data: "col1"},
        {title: "Column 2 n", data: "col2"}, // Rename
        {title: "Column 3", data: "col3"},
        {title: "Column 4", data: "col4"} // New
    ],
    order: [
        [0, 'asc'], // Change
        [1, 'desc'] // Change
    ],
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    bDestroy: true // Add this property to new setting
}

var dt = $('#tableId').DataTable(nTableOptions);
// Or
var dt = $('#tableId').html("").DataTable(nTableOptions);
```

Comment: So in other words... destroy the entire table and re-draw it from scratch? That clearly isn't ideal, because that means I have to have all of the same initial table options available, in order to re-create the table. Do I really have to do something so drastic? I was hoping for some simpler way of just updating properties.